# pickle.dump(model,pickle_out) | TypeError: can't pickle _thread._local objects

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pickle, dump

After successfully training traffic signs with tensorflow I would like to pickle the results. I am using tensorflow version 2.0.0, keras 2.3.1 and python 3.7.11.

In the last lines I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/t1/39jk5mmd66b2prn30v34_61c0000gn/T/ipykernel_32516/1492349104.py in <module>
    224 # STORE THE MODEL AS A PICKLE OBJECT
    225 pickle_out= open("model_trained.p","wb")  # wb = WRITE BYTE
--> 226 pickle.dump(model,pickle_out)
    227 pickle_out.close()
    228 cv2.waitKey(0)

TypeError: can't pickle _thread._local objects
```

Training pictures:
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AZeKw90Cb6GgamTBO3mvDdz6PjBwqCCt/view][1]

Labels:
[https://usercontent.one/wp/www.computervision.zone/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/labels.zip?media=1632743877][2]

Source code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Conv3D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, Flatten
import cv2
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pickle
import os
import pandas as pd
import random
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
 
tf.config.experimental.set_visible_devices([], 'GPU') # deactivates my slow gpu
 
################# Parameters #####################
 
path = "myData" # folder with all the class folders
labelFile = 'labels.csv' # file with all names of classes
batch_size_val=50  # how many to process together
steps_per_epoch_val=2000
epochs_val=10
imageDimesions = (32,32,3)
testRatio = 0.2    # if 1000 images split will 200 for testing
validationRatio = 0.2 # if 1000 images 20% of remaining 800 will be 160 for validation
###################################################
 
 
############################### Importing of the Images
count = 0
images = []
classNo = []
myList = os.listdir(path)
print("Total Classes Detected:",len(myList))
noOfClasses=len(myList)
print("Importing Classes.....")
for x in range (0,len(myList)-1):
    myPicList = os.listdir(path+"/"+str(count))
    for y in myPicList:
        curImg = cv2.imread(path+"/"+str(count)+"/"+y)
        images.append(curImg)
        classNo.append(count)
    print(count, end =" ")
    count +=1
print(" ")
images = np.array(images)
classNo = np.array(classNo)
 
############################### Split Data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(images, classNo, test_size=testRatio)
X_train, X_validation, y_train, y_validation = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=validationRatio)
 
# X_train = ARRAY OF IMAGES TO TRAIN
# y_train = CORRESPONDING CLASS ID
 
############################### TO CHECK IF NUMBER OF IMAGES MATCHES TO NUMBER OF LABELS FOR EACH DATA SET
print("Data Shapes")
print("Train",end = "");print(X_train.shape,y_train.shape)
print("Validation",end = "");print(X_validation.shape,y_validation.shape)
print("Test",end = "");print(X_test.shape,y_test.shape)
assert(X_train.shape[0]==y_train.shape[0]), "The number of images in not equal to the number of lables in training set"
assert(X_validation.shape[0]==y_validation.shape[0]), "The number of images in not equal to the number of lables in validation set"
assert(X_test.shape[0]==y_test.shape[0]), "The number of images in not equal to the number of lables in test set"
assert(X_train.shape[1:]==(imageDimesions))," The dimesions of the Training images are wrong "
assert(X_validation.shape[1:]==(imageDimesions))," The dimesionas of the Validation images are wrong "
assert(X_test.shape[1:]==(imageDimesions))," The dimesionas of the Test images are wrong"
 
 
############################### READ CSV FILE
data=pd.read_csv(labelFile)
print("data shape ",data.shape,type(data))
 
############################### DISPLAY SOME SAMPLES IMAGES  OF ALL THE CLASSES
#num_of_samples = []
#cols = 5
#num_classes = noOfClasses
#fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=num_classes, ncols=cols, figsize=(5, 300))
#fig.tight_layout()
#for i in range(cols):
#    for j,row in data.iterrows():
#        x_selected = X_train[y_train == j]
#        axs[j][i].imshow(x_selected[random.randint(0, len(x_selected)- 1), :, :], cmap=plt.get_cmap("gray"))
#        axs[j][i].axis("off")
#        if i == 2:
#            axs[j][i].set_title(str(j)+ "-"+row["Name"])
#            num_of_samples.append(len(x_selected))
 
 
############################### DISPLAY A BAR CHART SHOWING NO OF SAMPLES FOR EACH CATEGORY
#print(num_of_samples)
#plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
#plt.bar(range(0, num_classes), num_of_samples)
#plt.title("Distribution of the training dataset")
#plt.xlabel("Class number")
#plt.ylabel("Number of images")
#plt.show()
 
############################### PREPROCESSING THE IMAGES
 
def grayscale(img):
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return img
def equalize(img):
    img =cv2.equalizeHist(img)
    return img
def preprocessing(img):
    img = grayscale(img)     # CONVERT TO GRAYSCALE
    img = equalize(img)      # STANDARDIZE THE LIGHTING IN AN IMAGE
    img = img/255            # TO NORMALIZE VALUES BETWEEN 0 AND 1 INSTEAD OF 0 TO 255
    return img
 
X_train=np.array(list(map(preprocessing,X_train)))  # TO IRETATE AND PREPROCESS ALL IMAGES
X_validation=np.array(list(map(preprocessing,X_validation)))
X_test=np.array(list(map(preprocessing,X_test)))
cv2.imshow("GrayScale Images",X_train[random.randint(0,len(X_train)-1)]) # TO CHECK IF THE TRAINING IS DONE PROPERLY
 
############################### ADD A DEPTH OF 1
X_train=X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0],X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2],1)
X_validation=X_validation.reshape(X_validation.shape[0],X_validation.shape[1],X_validation.shape[2],1)
X_test=X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0],X_test.shape[1],X_test.shape[2],1)
 
 
############################### AUGMENTATAION OF IMAGES: TO MAKEIT MORE GENERIC
dataGen= ImageDataGenerator(width_shift_range=0.1,   # 0.1 = 10%     IF MORE THAN 1 E.G 10 THEN IT REFERS TO NO. OF  PIXELS EG 10 PIXELS
                            height_shift_range=0.1,
                            zoom_range=0.2,  # 0.2 MEANS CAN GO FROM 0.8 TO 1.2
                            shear_range=0.1,  # MAGNITUDE OF SHEAR ANGLE
                            rotation_range=10)  # DEGREES
dataGen.fit(X_train)
batches= dataGen.flow(X_train,y_train,batch_size=20)  # REQUESTING DATA GENRATOR TO GENERATE IMAGES  BATCH SIZE = NO. OF IMAGES CREAED EACH TIME ITS CALLED
X_batch,y_batch = next(batches)
 
# TO SHOW AGMENTED IMAGE SAMPLES
fig,axs=plt.subplots(1,15,figsize=(20,5))
fig.tight_layout()
 
for i in range(15):
    axs[i].imshow(X_batch[i].reshape(imageDimesions[0],imageDimesions[1]))
    axs[i].axis('off')
plt.show()
 
 
y_train = to_categorical(y_train,noOfClasses)
y_validation = to_categorical(y_validation,noOfClasses)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test,noOfClasses)
 
############################### CONVOLUTION NEURAL NETWORK MODEL
def myModel():
    no_Of_Filters=60
    size_of_Filter=(5,5) # THIS IS THE KERNEL THAT MOVE AROUND THE IMAGE TO GET THE FEATURES.
                         # THIS WOULD REMOVE 2 PIXELS FROM EACH BORDER WHEN USING 32 32 IMAGE
    size_of_Filter2=(3,3)
    size_of_pool=(2,2)  # SCALE DOWN ALL FEATURE MAP TO GERNALIZE MORE, TO REDUCE OVERFITTING
    no_Of_Nodes = 500   # NO. OF NODES IN HIDDEN LAYERS
    model= Sequential()
    model.add((Conv2D(no_Of_Filters,size_of_Filter,input_shape=(imageDimesions[0],imageDimesions[1],1),activation='relu')))  # ADDING MORE CONVOLUTION LAYERS = LESS FEATURES BUT CAN CAUSE ACCURACY TO INCREASE
    model.add((Conv2D(no_Of_Filters, size_of_Filter, activation='relu')))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=size_of_pool)) # DOES NOT EFFECT THE DEPTH/NO OF FILTERS
 
    model.add((Conv2D(no_Of_Filters//2, size_of_Filter2,activation='relu')))
    model.add((Conv2D(no_Of_Filters // 2, size_of_Filter2, activation='relu')))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=size_of_pool))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
 
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(no_Of_Nodes,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5)) # INPUTS NODES TO DROP WITH EACH UPDATE 1 ALL 0 NONE
    model.add(Dense(noOfClasses,activation='softmax')) # OUTPUT LAYER
    # COMPILE MODEL
    model.compile(Adam(lr=0.001),loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
 
 
############################### TRAIN
model = myModel()
#print(model.summary())
history=model.fit_generator(dataGen.flow(X_train,y_train,batch_size=batch_size_val),steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch_val,epochs=epochs_val,validation_data=(X_validation,y_validation),shuffle=1)
 
############################### PLOT
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.legend(['training','validation'])
plt.title('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.legend(['training','validation'])
plt.title('Acurracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.show()
score =model.evaluate(X_test,y_test,verbose=0)
print('Test Score:',score[0])
print('Test Accuracy:',score[1])
 
# STORE THE MODEL AS A PICKLE OBJECT
pickle_out= open("model_trained.p","wb")  # wb = WRITE BYTE
pickle.dump(model,pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Thx for Your help! :)
[1]: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AZeKw90Cb6GgamTBO3mvDdz6PjBwqCCt/view
[2]: https://usercontent.one/wp/www.computervision.zone/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/labels.zip?media=1632743877

Answer (score 0):

As of now, Keras models are pickle-able. But we still recommend using `model.save()` to save model to disk.